# Simple textured quad rotation in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, rotation, opengl-es-2.0, transformation

**Edit 6** - Complete re-write in relation to comments/ongoing research

**Edit 7** - Added projection / view matrix.....

As I'm not getting far with this, I added view/projection matrix from the Google demo - please see code below:  If anyone can point out where I'm going wrong it really would be appreciated, as I'm still getting a blank screen when I put ""gl_position = a_position * uMVPMatrix;" + into my vertex shader (with "gl_position = a_position;" + my quad is displayed at least.......)

**Declared at class level: (Quad class)**

```
    private final float[] rotationMat = new float[16];
    private FloatBuffer flotRotBuf;
    ByteBuffer rotBuf;
    private int muRotationHandle = -1;              // Handle to the rotation matrix in the vertex shader called "uRotate"
```

**Declared at class lever: (Renderer class)**

```
    private final float[] mVMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mProjMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
```

**Routine that sets texture and does (or is supposed to do) rotation (This is in my Quad class**

```
public void setTexture(GLSurfaceView view, Bitmap imgTexture, float[] mvpMatrix){
        this.imgTexture=imgTexture;

      // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "uMVPMatrix");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

//      Matrix.setRotateM(rotationMat, 0, 45f, 0, 0, 1.0f);    //Set rotation matrix with angle and (z) axis

//       rotBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(rotationMat.length * 4);
         // use the device hardware's native byte order
//       rotBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
         // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
//       flotRotBuf = rotBuf.asFloatBuffer();
         // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
//       flotRotBuf.put(rotationMat);
         // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
//       flotRotBuf.position(0);

//       muRotationHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "uRotation");  // grab the variable from the shader
//       GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muRotationHandle, 1, false, flotRotBuf); //Pass floatbuffer contraining rotation matrix info into vertex shader
         //GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muRotationHandle, 1, false, rotationMat, 1); //Also tried this ,not use floatbuffer

        //Vertex shader
        String strVShader =  
            //    "uniform mat4 uRotation;" +
                  "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                  "attribute vec4 a_position;\n"+
                  "attribute vec2 a_texCoords;" +
                  "varying vec2 v_texCoords;" +
                  "void main()\n" +
                  "{\n" +
                  "gl_Position = a_Position * uMVPMatrix;"+  //This is where it all goes wrong....         
                  "v_texCoords = a_texCoords;" +
                  "}";

        //Fragment shader

        String strFShader =
            "precision mediump float;" +
            "varying vec2 v_texCoords;" +
            "uniform sampler2D u_baseMap;" +
            "void main()" +
            "{" +
            "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_baseMap, v_texCoords);" +
            "}";


        iProgId = Utils.LoadProgram(strVShader, strFShader);
        iBaseMap = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(iProgId, "u_baseMap");
        iPosition = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(iProgId, "a_position");
        iTexCoords = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(iProgId, "a_texCoords");
        texID = Utils.LoadTexture(view, imgTexture);

    }
```

**From my renderer class:**

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Set viewport size based on screen dimensions      
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);

}

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //Paint the screen the colour defined in onSurfaceCreated
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mVMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);


    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mVMatrix, 0);

    quad1.setTexture(curView, myBitmap, mMVPMatrix);  //SetTexture now modified to take a float array (See above) - Note I know it's not a good idea to have this in my onDrawFrame method - will move it once I have it working!

    quad1.drawBackground(); 
}
```

I've now removed all rotation related stuff and am now just attempting to get a static quad to display after applying the uMVPMatrix in the vertex shader.  But still nothing :-(

If I simply change that line back to the 'default' :

```
    "gl_Position = a_position;\n"+
```

Then I at least get my textured quad displayed (Obviously no rotation and I would expect that).

Also just to point out, that mvpMatrix is definately being received intact into the setTexture method is valid (contains the same data as appears when I log the contents of mvpMatrix from the Google developers code).  I'm not sure how to check if the shader is receiving it intact?  I have no reason to believe it isn't though.

Really do appreciate and and all help - I must be going very wrong somewhere but I just can't spot it.  Thank you!

**EDIT 2**: Having added a bounty to this question, I would just like to know how how to rotate my textured quad sprite (2D) keeping the code I have to render it as a base. (ie, what do I need to add to it in order to rotate and why).  Thanks!

**EDIT 3** N/A

**EDIT 4** Re-worded / simplified question

**EDIT 5** Added error screenshot

[image]

Comment: In glUniformMatrix4v false != GL_FALSE. false is a c++ keyword, and GL_FALSE is an enum.

Comment: Also, it seems like you never apply your uMVPMatrix in your vertex shader. If you do not need to apply this, don't list it as a uniform and don't apply it in the fix.

Comment: If I put GL_FALSE, I just get "GL_FALSE cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: So my line in the V-Shader should be "gl_Position * vec4(a_position,1.0f);"+  and I shouldn't declare uMVPMatrix (I did realise this wasn't being declared in the code).  Maybe I should just forget about rotation!!! Lol

Comment: Well, if you are not transforming your vertex positions into world, view or projection space than you can keep the vertex shader as is. Rotation can be applied by saying `gl_Position = uRotation * a_position;`

Comment: Been reading up a bit on this - nope I'm not using a model view projection matrix at all.  So, does this simplify things?  Sorry, I still don't understand what code I need to use to make the quad rotate. I think I may have been overcomplicating things........?

Comment: Is it simply a case of creating a rotation matrix then applying the rotate with .setRotate, then passing the result to the vertex shader and multiplying it by the a_position variable to produce the rotation? I.E, making an calls to Matrix.multiplyMM redundant as I have nothing to multiply it with?  Or am I now over-simplifying things?

Comment: Well, all you need to do is create a rotation matrix from an identity matrix (as shown in my example) and apply it in the vertex shader (as shown in my example) associated with drawing the quad. I'm not sure what you mean by "apply the rotate with setRotate" as the rotation is only truly applied in the vertex shader.

Comment: Sorry, but why aren't you sending through a projection matrix (usually called MVPMatrix, but not required)? Are you not doing a perspective yet?

Comment: @SirDigbyChick wenCaesar, I think this is what I have been doing. I declare rotation matrix, set it using the setRotateM() method (with angel/axis etc), pass it to the (v) shader variable, then try to multiply the result in the v-shader. But I get nothing on the screen when I do this. Also tried moving the contents of the rotation matrix to a floatbuffer and passing that to the shader variable but get the same result. As noted, I'm not applying a projection matrix, could this be the problem? I've edit my Q with all the updated code/info. Again, thanks I really do appreciate your help here :-)

Comment: on edit 5 the error is the floatBuffer, should be a pointer to the first element of the matrix (you need to type cast?) also are you using angles divisible by 90 degrees? you might be getting the correct result but you cant see the image since it is rendered perpendicular to the screen? also gl_Position is case sensitive, im seeing some of your text with gl_position.

Comment: your a_position, too is case sensitive. check your shader

Comment: Thanks @DanPro, I've actually removed all of my rotation related stuff (I was going for 45 degrees) and am now just applying a projection matrix but getting the same results (blank screen).

Comment: i see nothing wrong with the mvpmatrix, either your quad is outside the view frustum or culling is enabled (you're seeing the back of your quad). for the meantime try `Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, -10, 10); gl_Disable(GL_CULL_FACE)` and see if it renders your quad.

Comment: Tanks @DanPro I actually managed to get it working and have also applied rotation, but for some reason it is rotating the quad around the screen rather than around it's own centre (ie I simply want the quad to 'spin' (like a wheel).  But that's another issue I guess!

Comment: you just need to put the rotation matrix to the other side when you multiply it with the mvpMatrix. matrix multiplication is not commutative. :)

Comment: Hi @DanPro, do you mean in the Vertex shader? Trouble is, if I do that, it kind of 'skews' when I rotate it although you're right, I can change the centre of rotation! I initially had it set like that but swapped it because of the skewing - any idea how I get rid of this skewing effect?  Cheers!

Comment: the skewing is, again, from incorrect order of multiplying transformation matrices. the order is important, you need to scale it first, then rotate before applying translation. also, to get the mvpMatrix, you need to do this in order: worldMatrix*viewMatrix*projectionMatrix.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation matrix for rotation around z:

```
cos a -sin a 0
sin a  cos a 0
    0      0 1
```

How to remember how to construct it:
a is the angle in radians, for a = 0 the matrix yields the identity-matrix. cos has to be on the diagonal. There has to be one sign in front of one sin, switching the signs inverses the rotation's direction.

Likewise rotations around x and y can be constructed:

```
1      0     0
0  cos a sin a
0 -sin a cos a

 cos a 0 sin a
     0 1     0
-sin a 0 cos a
```

If you are not familiar with matrix-arithmetic, here is some code:

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    vertices_new[i*5+0] = cos(a) * vertices[i*5+0] - sin(a) * vertices[i*5+1]; // cos(a) * v[i].x - sin(a) * v[i].y + 0 * v[i].z
    vertices_new[i*5+1] = sin(a) * vertices[i*5+0] + cos(a) * vertices[i*5+1]; // sin(a) * v[i].x + cos(a) * v[i].y + 0 * v[i].z
    vertices_new[i*5+2] = vertices[i*5+2]; // 0 * v[i].x + 0 * v[i].y + 1 * v[i].z
    vertices_new[i*5+3] = vertices[i*5+3]; // copy texture u
    vertices_new[i*5+4] = vertices[i*5+4]; // copy texture v
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on what is happening in your code please @TobiasSchlegel and also, could you give me an indication of how I would implement that into the code I originally posted - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Edited to support Java using Android SDK.

As Tobias indicated, the idiomatic solution to any vertex transformation in OpenGL is accomplished through the use of matrix operations. If you plan to continue developing with OpenGL, it is important that you (eventually) understand the underlying linear algebra involved in matrix operations, but it is often best to utilize a math library for abstracting  linear algebra computation into a more readable format. Under the android environment, you should manipulate float arrays with the [matrix][1] class to create a rotation matrix like this:

```
// initialize rotation matrix
float[16] rotationMat; 
Matrix.setIdentityM(rotationMat,0); 

// angle in degrees to rotate
float angle = 90;

// axis to rotate about (z axis in your case)
float[3] axis = { 0.0,0.0,1.0};

// For your case, rotate angle (in degrees) about the z axis. 
Matrix.rotateM(rotationMat,0,angle,axis[0],axis[1],axis[2]);
```

Then you can bind the rotation Matrix to a shader program like this:

```
// assuming shader program is currently bound ...
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "uRotation"), 1, GL_FALSE, rotationMat);
```

Where your vertex shader (of the program being passed `rotationMat`) would look something like:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
uniform mat4 uRotation;
attribute vec2 a_texCoords;
attribute vec3 a_position;
varying v_texCoord;

void main(void)
{
    v_texCoord = a_texCoords;
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix* uRotation * vec4(a_position,1.0f);
}
```

Alternatively, you could premultiply `uMVPMatrix* uRotation` outside of this shader program and pass the result to your shader program to avoid excessive duplicate computation.

Once you are comfortable using this higher level API for matrix operations you can investigate how the internal operation is performed by reading [this](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut06%20Rotation.html#d0e6309) fantastic tutorial written by [Nicol Bolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas).

Comment: Hey @SirDigbyChickenCaesa, thanks for this I will certainly have a look at the tut link you sent. I've heard of GLM Before but never looked into it. Am I correct in assuming this is C?  And if so, would I need to implement it as such (with NDK I assume?),  If so is there any way I can do this rotation just using the SDK/Java? Thanks again!!

Comment: Wow, sorry! I'm so used to thinking in the C++ head space when using OpenGL that I forgot you were most likely using Java on Android. I'll  look for a capable java math library and I will edit the post.

Comment: Wow this it's not as easy as I thought.  I think there are licensing issues with vecmath? Any other options? I've got the code from the Android developers that draws a rotating triangle in the center of the screen but for the life of me when I try to transplant the code to mine I get nothing.  It's when I change my ""gl_Position = a_Position;" line in my shader to "gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * a_Position;" I will post some code..... Thank you again

Comment: The code I'm trying to adapt is this: https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html and works great.  I can set change the code to set the angle at a specific amount etc but I can't see where any maths is happening, or how it is working out the actual rotate.  When I try to implement it I get nothing, just a blank screen basically - any idea what I could be missing?  My structure is slightly different to the code as I have my own rendering method that I've written (as above)........again, any help would be appreciated, I've been on this one for a while! Thanks

Comment: Oh, well it seems android has a class specifically for handling matrix operations in opengl. See my revised answer.

Comment: I've just created a floatBuffer for the rotation matrix, I will see what happens.......!!

Comment: OK I've edited my question to show what my current drawing method as well as my texture method looks like - clearly I'm doing something wrong! Every time I try to edit the vertex shader I just get a blank screen!! :-( Hoping you can see where I'm going wrong.  Thank you again and sorry this is dragging on :-(

Comment: I still haven't got rotation to work, but by starting from scratch I have now managed to get a view / projection matrix working (No idea why my code above didn't work though).  This answer led me to looking at view / projection matrices so I have awarded the bounty to you @SirDigbyChckenCaesar as I'm on the right path now at least, thank you very much for your suggestions much appreciated.