# Changing level of opacity in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, opacity, sprite

**EDIT 1**: Included shaders

**EDIT 2**: Included screen-shots

**EDIT 3**: Included screen-shot of original texture

**EDIT 4**:

**EDIT 5**: I think the problem is because my bitmaps have partially transparent pixels in them to start with, so I will ask a new question as the answer given here is correct for this question.

On closer inspection, the problem doesn't quite appear to be resolved, colours aren't looking correct.

```
String strFShader =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "uniform float Opacity;" +
        "varying vec2 v_texCoords;" +
        "uniform sampler2D u_baseMap;" +
        "void main()" +
        "{" +
        "gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_baseMap, v_texCoords);" +
        "gl_FragColor.a *= Opacity;"+            
        "}";
```

And then in my rendering method:

```
    //Enable and set mode
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND); 
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

//Draw
GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

//Disable
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
```

So, at max transparency (0.0), it's all good, i.e. nothing gets drawn.  However at any other level it's not quite right, For example, at zero transparency (opacity set to 1.0), this is what I get:

![enter image description here][1]

But it should actually look like this:

![enter image description here][2]

Colours looks a little too dark and, (on the original image), the ever so slightly dark edge is really pronounced.

I'm assuming it's something to do with the blending mode?  Basically I'm simply after the effect one might get in photoshop when changing the opacity of one layer over another.  Any other suggestions would be very helpful.

I also tried the solution found here:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7260/opengl-es-basic-fragment-shader-help-with-transparency

But I get the same results?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, change your `glBlendFunc` to `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Rendering with opacity is handled by the shader program that is bound during the draw operation performed after the call to `glBlendFunc`. More specifically, this is specified by the alpha component of the gl_FragColor output of the bound program's fragment shader. The following fragment shader shows an very simple example of how you could utilize your shader program to accomplish a fade effect.

```
precision mediump float;
uniform float Opacity; // range 0.0 to 1.0
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_baseMap;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_baseMap, v_texCoords) ;
    gl_FragColor.a *= Opacity;
}
```

Where you would bind the current opacity of the foreground layer to the shader program uniform `Opacity`. In your case, since you want the foreground layer to fade in you will simply perform the complete draw operation (background layer then foreground layer) many times with a chosen time step between operations to achieve a smooth fade.

**Also**: Remember to disable the blend state EACH time after you draw the foreground objects. It is always good practice in OpenGL to reset a value to it's previous state once an operation is completed. Forgetting to do so can cause some serious headaches.

Comment: Thanks for this it's much appreciated. I've edited my question to include my shaders.  Please could you show how I would implement this into my shaders. I'm still not 100% clear as I'm using textures - thank you!

Comment: Thanks again for your continued help, I've added some screen shots to show what happens when I implement this - any idea where I'm going wrong?  Thanks once again

Comment: Try changing your `glBlendFunc` to 
`glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Comment: It is slightly better in that with the opacity value set to 0.0, it is completely invisible as would be expected, however, if I increase the values. it fades everything in (black box around the face included) so almost there!

Comment: See my above edit. Your `u_baseMap` sampler MUST be bound to an RGBA texture in order for this to work. i.e. your smiley face texture must define the black areas as having 0 or near 0 alpha.

Comment: Hi, do you mean the original png file?  If so, it definitely has an alpha channel.  I can actually get it to display correctly if I remove the code from the shader but keep the blend function.  It's just changing the opacity level I'm having problems with :-(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you had edited the code you originally had in the fragment shader! I've made the changes to reflect and it is now working perfectly - thank you so much.  If you have time maybe you could look at my other question regarding rotating the same quad.  There's an oustanding +50 bounty on it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626351/simple-textured-quad-rotation-in-opengl-es-2-0  Thanks again :-)